# ContextMenu configuration in Notepad++ for dialog commands

Tags: notepad++

I want to find all references of a particular text in the current document. Easily done through the Find dialog using the 'Find All in Current Document' button.

Now I want to add this to the context menu.

Per [these instructions](https://npp-user-manual.org/docs/config-files/#the-context-menu-contextmenu-xml), the way to do it is to get the option added by using the ID from [this list](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/blob/master/PowerEditor/installer/nativeLang/english.xml).

However, adding

```
<Item id="1641"/>
```

only results in a blank row in the context menu. Adding a 'name' attribute does not help either

Is there a way to include a dialog command in the context menu.

Comment: Did you try putting it in with the full description, as `<Item id="1641" name="Find All in Current Document"/>`?

Comment: That does not help. I hadn't tried 'name' earlier; had used 'MenuItemName'. Neither of them work.